# println() in Spring Boot logs

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, logging

I use `System.out.println()` to debug my Spring Boot application. It is fine in my IDE. When run standalone, there is a strange situation when `println` from my `@Controller` prints to the console, but `println` from my `@RestController` doesn't (I see them both printing to the output in the IDE). I have this in `application.properties`:

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.directory=/dev
server.tomcat.accesslog.prefix=stdout
server.tomcat.accesslog.buffered=false
server.tomcat.accesslog.suffix=
server.tomcat.accesslog.file-date-format=
```

I am not sure what these constants mean. Is there a method of having all `println` from all threads print to the console? The `@RestController` executes, because Tomcat shows that it has been called, it returns 200 and the application works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefer using logs (slf4j, log4j) instead of System.out.println
With right configuration, it will write your logs in a file ".log", with date and time of traces (info, debug, warn, error levels)
It is more appropriate if you want to deploy your app on a remote server.